# How to reload nginx run as a docker swarm service?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I have a https nginx server run as docker swarm service. After updating the certificates, how could I ask nginx to reload them?

`docker service update --force` seems to restart the service so clients would be interrupted?

And there is no `docker service run` that I can run `nginx -s reload`.

What should I do to reload nginx without restarting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want zero downtime then here is one apparoach:

Scale nginx service to 2 then update nginx service. While updating the service, it will do one by one by default. So that user won't be seeing any downtime.

You can control this in docker-compose.yaml file.

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: REPO:TAG
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
```

'parallelism: 1' will update the container one by one.

Comment: Will docker wait for clients to disconnect when stopping a replica?